# Can't export dataframes and other objects to Excel using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to export multiple dataframes to a single spreadsheet in excel from Pandas.

I keep getting the error:
'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

despite never importing numpy. Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import xlwings as xw

... dataframe calculations ...

# Export to Excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/users/test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')   
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('PythonCalculations')
writer.sheets['PythonCalculations'] = worksheet
myNumber.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='PythonCalculations',startrow = 0 , startcol=0)   
df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='PythonCalculations',startrow = 2, startcol = 0)
```

Where, for example, myNumber = 100. Type is  numpy.int64. whenever I try to execute that line with myNumber in it, it keeps returning the error 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_excel'.

When I try to execute the line with df1, it manages to execute, however no excel file is created. Even when I created the excel file and ran the lines, it didn't populate. How do I fix this?

Comment: `df1` is not a `pd.DataFrame` object it is a `numpy.int64` object. We need to see the full code to see where you overwrote the df1 variable with and int. And we need to see the full traceback of the error.

Comment: When i executed type(df1), it returned pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. df1 is a dataframe. myNumber is a numpy.int64 object

Comment: Oh, if `myNumber` is a `numpy.int64`, why do you think you can do `numpy.int64.to_excel()`? `to_excel()` is a `pd.Dataframe` attribute not a `numpy.int64` attribute

Comment: because I am unsure of how exactly to export that to excel.. and was looking here for help. Also, as mentioned, an actual Pandas Dataframe did not execute to excel either

Comment: the error occurs before`df1.to_excel()` so that line is never executed.

Comment: No, Even when i opened a new console, and excluded the line that was a numpy.int64, it did not create an excel file, nor exported the dataframe, or anything

Comment: Use xlwings, it's a useful convenient library to import/export DF to/from excel files.

Comment: writer.save()
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_simple.html

Comment: You can't add a worksheet using a xlsxwriter object and then try to use it with `to_excel()`. Basically all 4 lines after `writer = pd.ExcelWriter()` have an error of some sort and should be removed. To see how to mix xlsxwriter and pandas and how to write multiple data frames to the same worksheet see the docs on [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also wonder why you don't just use xlwings. First make sure to take a look at the xlwings docs, https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html . Once you are able to connect you should be able to do something as simple as the below code. I'm not adding a worksheet, I'm using an existing worksheet.

```
wb = xw.Book('my_workbook.xlsm')
sht = wb.sheets['a_sheet_that_already_exists']
rng1 = sht.range('A1') # Ambiguous cell.
rng2 = sht.range('J2') # Ambiguous cell with enough room for df1.

# Your dataframe collections are df1 and df2.
# Showing .options in case you care.
rng1.options(index=True, header=True).value = df1
rng2.options(index=True, header=True).value = df2
```

Comment: Thank you, I did end up switching to xlwings.... It was just way more convenient